# Xiaomi 3s prime not able to read finger print on app lock

Tags: lock-screens, miui, fingerprint

Phone: xiaomi 3s prime with android 6 and
Miui 8.

I use finger print lock for apps.
When open such a apps,  screen shows
" couldn't read finger print.  Please enter your pattern"
But i forgot my alternate pattern password. 
The interesting point is am able to unlock my phone using finger print but above problem occur only with app lock.

I tried *#*#*6484*#*#* and tested my finger print sensor.  Its working fine.

Comment: For one app or for all apps?

Comment: @SagarV Thnx for Comments. Problem with all apps which i locked using app lock. Finally resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is settings issue where am using finger print lock for apps and messed with some settings .

Steps which resolved:

1)SETTINGS > > lock screen & passwords >> screen lock & finger print

2) Draw your screen lock pattern

3) switch on “app lock” under “apply finger print option to ”